# Can someone please clarify if this use of tense makes sense or not?

Tags: tenses, past-participles

In a recent contract I signed, there was something that misled me. The contract stated something in the following way:

"You must not have [done this] from [past time] until [future time]"

eg:

"You must not have played sport from yesterday until tomorrow"

The time used in place of 'tomorrow' was somewhat ambiguous to whether it was in the past or future.

Essentially, because of the initial past participle tense of "You must not have", I assumed that the from-until interval was entirely in the past. However, it is being claimed that I signed an agreement into the future.

Does the above statement make sense or would this need to be worded differently to refer to an interval running into the future?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "You must not have played sport from yesterday until tomorrow" would make sense if tomorrow is before another moment in time considered in the future. But you must give more context to make that clear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To add a more context: "You must not have played football from 10 days prior to the game until 5 days after your last game"

Comment: What @fev said. You can only combine the Perfect form ***must have*** and reference to some future time ***until tomorrow*** if the "narrative reference time" is that future time or later. For example, ***When you apply for Unemployment Benefit next week**, remember that you **must not have had** any paid employment from the beginning of the month until this coming weekend*.

Comment: They are claiming that 5 days after you last game includes '5 days after the game'

Comment: Thanks. It makes no mention of any narrative reference time and just states that "These are the requirements" before listing the requirements in a table with others such as "You must not...from [future date] until [future date]". For example "These are the requirements: 1) You must not have played football from 10 days prior to the game until 5 days after your last game 2) You must not play baseball from [future time] until [future time] 3) You must not...". Do you agree that '5 days after your last game' referring to a potential future date would be incorrect in this context?